# Upgrade from 14.04 Trusty to 16.04 Xenial aborted

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

The software updater asked me this week if I wanted to upgrade to Xenial, I decided to wait for the week-end to deal with any complications. I was impressed that pretty much everything happened in-place, but the process aborted with errors, and I got a message saying that my computer might be in an unstable state. I have a few questions:

- Is there an upgrade report that would have been saved somewhere so I can try to find out what went wrong and fix it / share it on AskUbuntu and ask for help?
- At the first restart, I got a lot of messages about truncating orphan blocks on the HDD before the logscreen, and then a lot of errors at the first login, but the second time was fine. Now apart from a few softwares, it seems that everything is working, but I'm worried about being "*in an unstable state*". How can I check if everything is ok? And if there is no way, does that mean my computer is unsafe to use / should I redo a clean install?

Answer (score 0):

I would do an `apt-get --fix-broken install` to see if it corrects any broken package. In all cases where I have had problems with broken packages it has corrected the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it would seem there is no broken package in my case, only a lot of no-longer needed ones.